# ReactJS: change the value of an object's property with setState

Tags: reactjs, object, constructor, state, setstate

I have the following code in the costructor:

```
this.state = {
              messageBox: { open: false, title: 'title', content: 'content', onConfirm: function() {console.log('confirm')}, onCancel: function() {console.log('cancel')} },
            };
```

Now I would like to change only the `open` property with setState. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Spread Operator (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

```
this.setState({ messageBox: { ...this.state.messageBox, open: true } });
```

Using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
this.setState({ messageBox: Object.assign({}, this.state.messageBox, { open: true } ) });
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered very well here:

[How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

But IMO the best answers are the ones that point out that nested state is not supported directly for a reason, and should probably be avoided if possible.